# Given $Q_{n+1}$ what is $Q_n$

Tags: notation, fractions

Given :

$$
Q_{n+1}=Q_n+\frac{1}{n}[R_n - Q_n]
$$

I'm attempting to understand the value of $Q_n$

Is the following correct ? :

$$
Q_{n}=Q_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-1}[R_{n-1} - Q_{n-1}]
$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Why don't you solve this difference equation for $Q_n$?

Comment: @Math-fun sorry, I don't understand how to solve a difference equation, Are you referring to https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob07.pdf ? Can you outline steps ?

Comment: Say $Q_0$ is known, then recursively solve for $Q_n$ as a function of $\{R_n\}$ and $Q_0$.